# How to match a url with specific pattern but not match very similar pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

How do we write a regular expression that will match:

```
https://example.com/username/method
```

where the **user** is any alphanumeric username

but not:

```
https://example.com/method
```

where there is no username present but the `method` name could be a valid username
e.g: `followers` such that a person with username "followers" would have a list of followers viewable at: https://example.com/followers/followers
(I know this is a *bizarre* example but its the edge case we are seeing!)

I searched StackOverflow and tried to write it: http://regexr.com/3bi27
but my RegEx Foo is not there (yet!)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about counting dashes instead of RegExp, or comparing the last index of a dash to 20?

Comment: We are *currently* using the `lastIndexOf` approach but were hoping for a cleaner way of doing it. thanks!

Comment: http://regexr.com/3bi2d

Comment: thanks @blueygh2 based on your solution we are using: http://regexr.com/3bi35 (we've up-voted your comment, next time leave as answer so we can accept it! thanks again!)

Comment: @nelsonic a link is too short to post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/qY5pH6/4
Just take a look. I would post it as comment, but I have no rights to do that.

> ((https|http)://)?example.com/(.*)/(.+)

Would match:

- https://example.com/username/delete
- https://example.com/admin/delete
- https://example.com/delete/admin
- example.com/method/admin
- example.com/any_w-o.rd/method
- example.com/any_aosja.asfdkkhsdfl.sfmdfh4/delete

But not: 
 - https://example.com/method

Comment: Thanks! that's *very* close to what we need! we need to match the exact method name. (*my question may not have been clear; I have updated it*).

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qY5pH6/5 I updated the regex. Maybe that is more close to your needs.